# Extract first element from the list that occurs after a particular word

Tags: python, python-3.x, pattern-matching, nltk

I have a `string` and a `list` as follow:

```
text = 'Sherlock Holmes. PARIS. Address: 221B Baker Street, london. Solving case in Madrid.'

city = ['Paris', 'London', 'Madrid']
```

I want to extract 1st element from the list that occurs after a word **Address**.

Here's my approach to problem using `nltk`

```
import nltk

loc = None
flag = False
for word in nltk.word_tokenize(text):
    if word == 'Address':
        flag = True

    if flag:
        if word.capitalize() in city:
            loc = word
            break

print(loc)
```

I am getting result as expected from above which is `london`.

But in real scenario my text is too large and list of cities too, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lowest hanging fruit I see is that you can turn `city` into a `set` for constant time membership checks. Besides that, consider using the `next` with default argument to return the next city.

```
city = {'Paris', 'London', 'Madrid'}
while text:
    text = text.partition('Address')[-1].strip()
    print(
        next((w for w in nltk.word_tokenize(text) if w.capitalize() in city), None))
```

Comment: it's returning none when I assign value of `next((w for w in nltk.word_tokenize(text) if w.capitalize() in city), None)` to a variable.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar That's only for the last city, since the last partition is usually empty. You can always just discard it at the end.

Comment: These are the time taken by my script `0.1093` and yours `0.0155`. I tested on small dataframe, it gave me improvement which is significant. Thanks :-)